# RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'take_message' was never awaited task(*args, **kwargs)

Tags: python, python-3.x, telethon

I write a bot, that work with the telethont and the telebot. The telebot need to listen a bot in the telegram, he sends commands. The telethon need to listen alien channels, and to parse posts. I want to add a opportunity, that will be to add many listens. But appear error: 
`/home/home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/util.py:60: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'take_message' was never awaited
  task(*args, **kwargs)`

How to fix this error?

Main code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import telebot
import asyncio

from telegram_client import TelegramSession as ts

api_id = ********************** # этот id вы получаете при создание приложения
api_hash = '***********************' # и этот тоже
username = '***************' # ваше имя в тг
id_channel = -***************** # id вашего канала
token = '********************' # токен вашего бота

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
client = ts(api_id,api_hash,username)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def take_message(message):
  if '@' in message.text and ',' in message.text:
    channels = message.text.split(',')
    my_channel = channels[-1]
    parse_channel = channels[0:-1]
    await client.add_task(parse_channel,my_channel)
  else:
    return bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'<b>Проверьте правильность ввода!</b>',parse_mode='html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Code the module telegram_client:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient,sync,events,utils
import asyncio

class TelegramSession:
  def __init__(self,api_id,api_hash,username):
    self.__loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(self.__loop)
    self.client = TelegramClient(username, api_id, api_hash,loop=self.__loop)
    self.client.start()

  async def handler_channel(self,parse_channel,my_channel):
    #print(parse_channel)
    @self.client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=parse_channel))
    async def normal_handler(event):
      await self.client.send_message(my_channel,event.message)

  async def list_tasks(self):
    pass

  async def add_task(self,parse_channel,my_channel):
    print(parse_channel)
    await self.__loop.create_task(self.handler_channel(parse_channel,my_channel))

  async def stop_task(self,something):
    pass

  def run_until(self):
    self.client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be mixing two frameworks here, `telebot` and `telethon`. `telethon` is based around the `async-await` syntax (asynchronous code) while `telebot` is not (synchronous code).

The fact that async and sync code don't play well together and can't easily be called from each other has been a major criticism of the introduction of `async-await` in Python.

Thus the issue is you have:

```
async def take_message(message):
    ...
    await client.add_task(parse_channel,my_channel)
```

when `telebot` expects:

```
def take_message(message):
    # ...and NO 'await's inside function body!
```

You *couuuuld* attempt to add the task you start in `take_message` to `telethon`'s event loop (using `loop.create_task`) inside the synchronous code, but I wouldn't recommend that. Instead, I would try to do what you need to do **using just one framework**, not both at once.

Comment: So, if i use `telebot.AsyncTelebot`, will that change anything?

Comment: Okey, but `telethon` can't work with a bot in the telegram.Yes? If yes, then how to listen a bot in the telegram?

Comment: My guess is that `telebot.AsyncTelebot` won't help as you will end up with two separate event loops.

Comment: I don't know which functionality `telethon` and `telebot` have. You would have to read the documentation to make sure. But your app seems simple so I would guess at least one of them has the functionality.

Comment: Ohhh... man, thank you very much)) I found in telethon methods, which work with the telegram bot) https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/concepts/botapi-vs-mtproto.html